# Implement Sort Merge Bucket Join in C++

Tags: c++, join, hive, bigdata

I am trying to implement Sort Merge Bucket Join (a feature of hive) in c++.

For starter, suppose I have 100 small files containing, say, 10 million rows of integers each, collectively representing a column, say, column 1 of 1 billion rows of a table and similarly another 100 similar files representing a similar column, say, column 2 of another table.

I want to essentially sort both the columns and write only those values in a different file(s) where the values in column 1 = values in column 2.

The catch is I do not want to read more than 10 million integers of each column in the RAM.

I am comfortable merging the columns as long as they are sorted, but do not know how can I sort the whole column without actually having the whole column in my RAM at a time.

I know this technique is implemented in hive but I am not well-versed in it and I cannot find any article on internet of any help to me.

And this goes without saying, I want to perform this operation as efficiently as possible.

How can I go about this problem? Or how does hive have been able to do it?

Comment: It depends on whether you may make a copy of data in single file; whether you can create multiple temporary files; how much memory you can take; etc. Generally you'll need some [External sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) algorithm for that.

Comment: For reference, see e.g. the section on External Merge Sort in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need. Are you saying you want to sort both columns _independently_ and then find _equal values at corresponding positions_? Then, for example, sorted data col1:(1, 2, 3, 4) and col2:(1, 2, 3, 3) would result in three pairs of equal numbers – i.e. (1,1), (2,2) and (3,3) – but col1:(1, 2, 3, 4), col2:(1, 1, 2, 3) would return just one such pair, (1,1). Am I right?

Comment: @CiaPan Think of it as a normal table join in SQL. For example, if one column is (1,2,3,4) and the other is (-1, 2, 1, 3). The result I want is (1,2,3) which is basically the intersection of the two set of values.

Comment: OK. So now there is another issue to consider: are values in each column unique? If they aren't do you want to treat them as distinguishable? For example, does joining (0, 1) with (1, 1) produce (1), because there is a value 1 in both columns, or (1, 1) because the 1 in the left colum matches two 1s in the right column?

Comment: @CiaPan Yes, in this case, we'll have only (1) as the output, i.e., the values are not distinguishable.